# Await within a waited dbcontext, should one use SaveChangesAsync on a context that is waited on using or SaveChanges() is enough

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, using, savechanges

If a dbcontext is waited on using should one still use SaveChangesAsync() or SaveChanges() should be enough?
`await using var dbContxt = new dbContxt(con);`

```
public async Task<bool> SaveData(strig con, object data)
{
    await using var dbContxt = new dbContxt(con);

    var myData = new MyData
    {
        a = data.a,
        b = data.b,
        c = data.c,
    };

    dbContxt.MyData.Add(myData);
    var result = await dbContxt.SaveChangesAsync();
    return result > 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer yes. In the scope of your async Task the DbContext will be alive.